How to select <Rule> according to env params in GeoServer SLD
I want to make some Rule depends on my env params.
if my params equals 'a',then select  a,
if my params euqals 'b',then select  b,
what should I do ?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"       
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
                       xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"                       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>hygz_lndare_area</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>hygz_lndare_area</Name>
      <Title>hygz_lndare_area</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>a</Name>
          <ogc:Filter>

            <ogc:Function name="env"> 
              <ogc:Literal>rule</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>

            <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>

          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#CCC57B</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

        <Rule>
          <Name>b</Name>
          <ogc:Filter>

            <ogc:Function name="env"> 
              <ogc:Literal>rule</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#181507</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

        <Rule>
          <Name>c</Name>
          <ogc:Filter>


            <ogc:Function name="env"> 
              <ogc:Literal>rule</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>

            <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>

          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#181507</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

        <Rule>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#CCC57B</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>


If you are only changing the fill colour then you could use a recode function to change the environment variable to a colour

thank you.but it just a example. i hope to apply it to other complicated styles,such as using SVG symbol as PointSymbolizer

Filters in SLD are designed to be evaluated for each feature in the data store, what you seem to be trying to do (if I understand your question) is to change the style for a whole map request. In that case you would be better off defining a number of styles and using the logic that was setting your environment variable to choose the correct style for the layer.
If you do proceed with checking the env variable for each feature then you probably want to look at the equalTo function, but I've never tried that with an environment variable.

ogc:Filter <ogc:Function name="equalTo">
it doesn't work, because    : Invalid content was found starting with element '{"ogc":Function}'. One of '{"ogc":spatialOps, "ogc":comparisonOps, "ogc":logicOps, "ogc":FeatureId}' is expected.

currently, i would choose the SLD File through WMS params 'styles:styleA'，but  idon’t want to make such lots of SLD files.
what i really  want  is to choose the  or 'Style'  according to 'env params'  ，rather than 'Properties'.

Yes you would need to compare the result of that function to true or false

And as I explained filters don't work that way. Multiple slds is the best, easiest and quickest way to do it

finally,I found a way to realize what I wanted
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
                       xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
                       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>hygz_lndare_area</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>lndare_area</Name>
      <Title>lndare_area</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>lndare_area</Name>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">

                <ogc:Function name="if_then_else">
                  <ogc:Function name="equalTo">
                    <ogc:Function name="env">
                      <ogc:Literal>colorPalette</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:Function>
                    <ogc:Literal>day</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Function>
                  <ogc:Literal>#CCC57B</ogc:Literal>

                  <ogc:Function name="if_then_else">
                    <ogc:Function name="equalTo">
                      <ogc:Function name="env">
                        <ogc:Literal>colorPalette</ogc:Literal>
                      </ogc:Function>
                      <ogc:Literal>dusk</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:Function>
                    <ogc:Literal>#3A3824</ogc:Literal>

                    <ogc:Function name="if_then_else">
                      <ogc:Function name="equalTo">
                        <ogc:Function name="env">
                          <ogc:Literal>colorPalette</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                        <ogc:Literal>night</ogc:Literal>
                      </ogc:Function>
                      <ogc:Literal>#181507</ogc:Literal>
                      <ogc:Literal>#CCC57B</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:Function>
                  </ogc:Function>
                </ogc:Function>

              </CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>

It's not perfect cuz it may goes wrong while doing with PointSymbolizer which using SVG OnlineResource and I dont know how to deal with it.

besides，'palette' is a keyword in geoserver，avoid using it , it trouble me alot

The recode function would be better for this

Thank you. this function simplified my writing work
